# How to design maven-checkstyle-plugin for YAML file validation?

Tags: java, maven, yaml, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I have been searching on the webs for YAML file validation chedestyle plugin but there are not any such plugin. there are many online YAML validation tools such as **YAMLLINT** which requires you to copy your yml file to them and validate but I am looking for a plugin which can validate all my yml files at real time within IDE itself.
can anyone tell me any approach to design such plugin an java ?

Comment: any example or Code pointer will be very helpful

Comment: Which IDE? This is important.

Comment: for Intellij idea ide

Comment: If you want to do it from the command line you can use `yamllint` + `yamllint-checkstyle`.

by doing 
```shell
yamllint -f parsable test.yaml | yamllint-checkstyle > yamllint-checkstyle.xml
```
https://yamllint.readthedocs.io
https://github.com/thomaspoignant/yamllint-checkstyle

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Maven project, then you can try [this](https://github.com/sylvainlaurent/yaml-json-validator-maven-plugin) plugin.